# Google Sheets Arrayforumula – reference previous row for IF/THEN calculation?

Tags: google-sheets

I've been trying to figure this out myself for the past 45 minutes and I don't think I'm any closer.

My question is regarding column T. It is calculating a running balance. I want to create an exception in how it's calculating when I enter a "balance" record (shown in column H – "Type").

See row 35 for where I'm running into this challenge. Since the record type of row 35 is "balance", I want to see 50,000 output into T35 – carried over from S35, as opposed to continuing the running balance from the previous record.

Any help?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GTxEPVzBW66aV13kIlreB-3hvHpii-4SzAQyb-Wxd9Y/edit#gid=2146170730

Comment: you have `isblank(J2:J),""` in V but what's the output you're expecting and in which column

Comment: I want to see 50,000 output into T35, since that record type is "balance". I edited my original post to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: I also hid the irrelevant columns. I imagine that may make the sheet easier to digest.

Comment: by balance you mean you add money to your account that's not due to selling. or it's like an update you need that restarts your account to 50k?

Comment: David, correct.

Comment: David, actually, this should clarify it even better. IDK why I didn't think of it first.

I added a column U that has copy/pasted formulas that shows exactly what I want to do with the Arrayformula in T.